# Does redis have a list of redis error messages available for reference?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I tried checking redis official documentation but i could not find error messages or codes.
Is there a list of redis error messages/codes for reference?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there's no complete list of error messages. The RESP2 protocol just specify that if the first byte starts with `-`, it's an error. You probably need to `grep` redis repo to find out all the possible values.

https://redis.io/topics/protocol

> For Errors the first byte of the reply is "-"